# how to solve "Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string at"

Tags: regex, perl

Below is my code. I want to print the data $1 and $2 in one row and split it with `,`. Why can't I print the data?

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

my $input = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.rpt.gz";
my $output = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.txt";

gunzip $input => $output
or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

open (FILE, '<',"$output") or die "Cannot open $output\n";

while (<FILE>) {
  my $line = $_;
  chomp ($line);

  if ($line =~ m/^\s+Timing Path Group \'(\S+)\'/) {
    $line = $1;

    if ($line =~ m/^\s+Levels of Logic:\s+(\S+)/) {
      $line = $2;
    }
  }
  print "$1,$2\n";
}

close (FILE);
```

Comment: I have fixed the indentation of your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in future. Good indentation is one of the best tools for making your code easy to understand. If you're going to ask a large number of strangers to read and understand your code, then it's only polite to make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: thank you. @DaveCross. sorry, this is my first of perl script.

Comment: The importance of good indentation is not unique to Perl. Pretty much any programming language you use will be easier to read if you indent it sensibly.

Answer (score 4):

The meat of your program is here:

```
if ($line =~ m/^\s+Timing Path Group \'(\S+)\'/) {
  $line = $1;

  if ($line =~ m/^\s+Levels of Logic:\s+(\S+)/) {
    $line = $2;
  }
}
```

The regex capturing variables (`$1`, `$2`, etc) are set when you match a string against a regex that contains sets of capturing parentheses. The first capturing parentheses set the value of `$1`, the second capturing parentheses set the value of `$2`, and so on. In order for `$2` to be given a value, you need to match against a regex that contains two sets of capturing parentheses.

Both of your regexes only contain a single set of capturing parentheses. Therefore only `$1` will be set on each of your matches. `$2` will never be given a value - leading to the warning that you are seeing.

You need to rethink the logic in your code. I'm not sure why you think `$2` will have a value here. Your code is a little confusing, so I'm unable to offer a more specific solution.

I can, however, give you some more general advice:

- Use lexical filehandles and the three-arg version of `open()`.

  ```
  open my $fh, '<', "$output"
  ```
- There is no need for the quotes around `$output`.

  ```
  open my $fh, '<', $output
  ```
- I know why you're doing it, but `$output` is a potentially confusing name for a file that you read from. Consider changing it.
- Always include `$!` in an `open()` error message.

  ```
  open my $fh, '<', $output or die "Cannot open '$output': $!\n";
  ```
- Your `$line` variable seems unnecessary. Why not just keep the row data in `$_`, which will simplify your code:

  ```
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp; # works on $_ by default
    if (/some regex/) { # works on $_ by default
      # etc...
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Rather than suggesting to use $_, which is susceptible to hidden issues due to being a superglobal used by everything, I would just change it to `while (my $line = <$fh>)` so $_ is not used at all.