# how to combine the code to make the output is on the same line?

Tags: perl, unix

Can you help me to combine both of these progeam to display the output in a  row with two columns? The first column is for `$1` and the second column is `$2`.

Kindly help me to solve this. Thank you :)

This is my code 1.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

my $input = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.rpt.gz";
my $output = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.txt";


gunzip $input => $output
  or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

open (FILE, '<',"$output") or die "Cannot open $output\n";

while (<FILE>) {
  my $line = $_;
  chomp ($line);

  if ($line=~ m/^\s+Timing Path Group \'(\S+)\'/) {
    $line = $1;
    print ("$1\n");
  }
}

close (FILE);
```

This is my code 2.

```
my $input = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.rpt.gz";
my $output = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.txt";

gunzip $input => $output
  or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

open (FILE, '<',"$output") or die "Cannot open $output\n";

while (<FILE>) {
  my $line = $_;
  chomp ($line);

  if ($line=~ m/^\s+Levels of Logic:\s+(\S+)/) {
     $line = $1;
     print ("$1\n");
  }
}

close (FILE);
```

this is my output for code 1 which contain 26 line of data:

```
**async_default**
**clock_gating_default**
Ddia_link_clk
Ddib_link_clk
Ddic_link_clk
Ddid_link_clk
FEEDTHROUGH
INPUTS
Lclk
OUTPUTS
VISA_HIP_visa_tcss_2000
ckpll_npk_npkclk
clstr_fscan_scanclk_pulsegen
clstr_fscan_scanclk_pulsegen_notdiv
clstr_fscan_scanclk_wavegen
idvfreqA
idvfreqB
psf5_primclk
sb_nondet4tclk
sb_nondetl2tclk
sb_nondett2lclk
sbclk_nondet
sbclk_sa_det
stfclk_scan
tap4tclk
tapclk
```

The output code 1 also has same number of line.

Comment: can you share sample input file and the required output to add clarity to your question.

Comment: Can you be sure that the two columns have the same height?

Comment: I've fixed your indentation again. Please do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Hi @stack0114106. my output code1 and code2 have 26 line of data. my required output is to combine the output code2 beside the output code1. it means that the last output has 2 columns (o/p code1 and o/p code2) with 26 rows. it is clear? tq

Comment: Hi @HåkonHægland. Yes both column has same height. Tq

Comment: Hi @DaveCross. Tq and sorry

Comment: Hi @stack0114106. I had shared my output code 1 at the question. output code two also have the number of data. tq

Comment: I'm not sure why you're showing us your output. Showing us your input would be far more useful!

Comment: What does "Tq" mean?

Answer (score 1):

`paste` is useful for this: assuming your shell is bash, then using [process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

```
paste <(perl script1.pl) <(perl script2.pl)
```

That emits columns separated by a tab character. For prettier output, you can pipe the output of paste to `column`

```
paste <(perl script1.pl) <(perl script2.pl) | column -t -s $'\t'
```

And with this, you con't need to try and "merge" your perl programs.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the two scripts and to output two items of data on the same line, you need to hold on until the end of the file (or until you have both data items) and then output them at once. So you need to combine both loops into one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict ;
use warnings ;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

my $input = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.rpt.gz";
my $output = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.txt";


gunzip $input => $output
    or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

open (FILE, '<',"$output") or die "Cannot open $output\n";

my( $levels, $timing );
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp ($line);

    if ($line=~ m/^\s+Levels of Logic:\s+(\S+)/) {
        $levels = $1;
    }
    if ($line=~ m/^\s+Timing Path Group \'(\S+)\'/) {
        $timing = $1;
    }
}
print "$levels, $timing\n";

close (FILE);
```

Comment: Hi @Corion. Tq for answering  my question. But why the output only print the last line of data? Actually, I have 26 line of data for each output of code 1 and code2.

Comment: this is my output for code 1 which contains 26 row of data.---------------------------------**async_default**
**clock_gating_default**
Ddia_link_clk
Ddib_link_clk
Ddic_link_clk
Ddid_link_clk
FEEDTHROUGH
INPUTS
Lclk
OUTPUTS
VISA_HIP_visa_tcss_2000
ckpll_npk_npkclk
clstr_fscan_scanclk_pulsegen
clstr_fscan_scanclk_pulsegen_notdiv
clstr_fscan_scanclk_wavegen
idvfreqA
idvfreqB
psf5_primclk
sb_nondet4tclk
sb_nondetl2tclk
sb_nondett2lclk
sbclk_nondet
sbclk_sa_det
stfclk_scan
tap4tclk
tapclk

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't given us one vital piece of information - what does the input data looks like. Most importantly, are the two pieces of information you're looking for on the same line?

[**Update:** Looking more closely at your regexes, I see it's possible for both pieces of information to be on the same line - as they are both supposed to be the first item on the line. It would be helpful if you were clearer about that in your question.]

I think this will do the right thing, no matter what the answer to your question is. I've also added the improvements I suggested in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593229/how-to-solve-use-of-uninitialized-value-2-in-concatenation-or-string-at):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

my $zipped   = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.rpt.gz";
my $unzipped = "par_disp_fabric.all_max_lowvcc_qor.txt";

gunzip $zipped => $unzipped
    or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

open (my $fh, '<', $unzipped) or die "Cannot open '$unzipped': $!\n";

my ($levels, $timing);

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;

    if (m/^\s+Levels of Logic:\s+(\S+)/) {
        $levels = $1;
    }
    if (m/^\s+Timing Path Group \'(\S+)\'/) {
        $timing = $1;
    }

    # If we have both values, then print them out and
    # set the variables to 'undef' for the next iteration
    if ($levels and $timing) {
        print "$levels, $timing\n";
        undef $levels;
        undef $timing;
    }
}

close ($fh);
```